# Change div colour depending on category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the woo-commerce plugin within my Wordpress environment and there are category pages which I need to change the colour of a div background depending on which category are you in.

So I have like a banner across the top which is found in 'archive-product.php'

the div is named '`publicationsHeader`'

I need it to change the background when you are category pages like so..

```
?product_cat=creative
```

I am a bit stuck on the best approach?

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="publicationsHeader">
    <section>
        <div class="introLeft">
            <h2>Publications</h2>
                <h3 style="font-size: 1.2em;
color: #fff;
line-height: 28px;
padding-top: 20px">We write and produce current, practical and highly effective publications that teachers and pupils can use with immediate effect. All resources have been revised for the 2014/15 academic year.</h3>   
        </div>    
        <div class="introRight">  
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/JaneConsidineEducation" target="_blank">
            <button style="background-image:url(img/facebookIcon.png)"></button>
            </a>        
            <a href="https://twitter.com/janeconsidine" target="_blank">
            <button style="background-image:url(img/twitterIcon.png)"></button>
            </a>    
        </div>
    </section>
</div>


.publicationsHeader{
    background-color: #e84b34;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding: 40px 0;
    height: auto;
    overflow:auto;
}

.publicationsHeader h2{
     font-size:3em; 
     color: #fff;
     text-shadow: 0px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.publicationsHeaderLeft{
    background-color: #fff; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    padding:40px 20px; 
    float:left; 
    width: 50%;
}

.publicationsHeaderLeft input{
    border: solid #ccc thin;
    width:95%;
    font-size:16px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.publicationsHeaderLeft textarea{
    border: solid #ccc thin;
    width:95%;
    font-size:16px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    resize:vertical;
}

.publicationsHeadereft button{
    background-color: #ec4a2c;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    font-size:16px; 
}

.publicationsHeaderRight{
    background-color: #fff; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    padding:40px 20px 160px 20px; 
    float:right; 
    width: 50%; 
}

.publicationsHeaderRight li{
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: Well I havnt placed any code in what I seeking is the best approach rather than somebody just telling me if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the `body_class()` function? It adds a bunch of class names to your body tag that reflect the current page; in the case of WooCommerce it will add classes for `.woocommerce`, `tax-product_cat` and a class identifying that particular category, such as: `.term-my-product-cat`.

Using these you could style everything quite simply:

```
.publicationsHeader{
    background-color: #e84b34; /* Default colour */
}
.term-product-cat-1 .publicationsHeader {
    background-color: red; /* Change background for header for category 1 only */
}
.term-product-cat-2 .pulicationsHeader {
    background-color:blue; /* Change background for category 2 */
}
```

You can [read more about body_class() here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class)

Answer (score 1):

First fetch the get data in a variable with some default:

```
$pcat = empty($_GET['product_cat']) ? 'default' : $_GET['product_cat'];
```

Then make your div like this:

```
<div id="publicationsHeader" class="<?php echo $pcat;?>">
</div>
```

Define a class in your css file like this:

```
.creative {
    background: url(images/creative.png);
}
.default {
    background: url(images/default.png);
}
```

Comment: Hm I can see why this would work but it does not seem to be displaying any color I changed what you suggest as a URL to a color.

Comment: If you want to use the color instead of image, just use background-color: #cccccc; instead of background:

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following: check which category is currently displaying and give the `$background` variable a color accordingly. Like so:

```
if(is_product_category('creative')){
$background = "#ffffff";
}
```

Then call the `$background`in the `style`setting of your div, like so:

```
<div id="publicationsHeader" style="background-color: <?php echo $background; ?>">Content goes here</div>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this working, am I missing something from the if statement here?

Comment: Might be a silly question, but did you wrap the `if(is_product_category))` in `<?php ?>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

You can grep the parameter `$_GET["product_cat"]` and wrap that in a `if`-clause to set the css-class of `publicationHeader` via javaScript.